# How to convert a curl request to python?

Tags: python, curl

I need to convert a curl statement to Python

```
curl -k -d 'id=id1'  --data-urlencode 'username=user1' --data-urlencode 'password=pass1' https://aaaa.bbb.com:nnnn
```

I was able to use

```
import requests

data = [
  ('id', 'id1'),
]

response = requests.post('https://aaaa.bbb.com/:nnnn', data=data)
```

With this I get certificate_verify_failed. How can I include urlencode for the username and password

Comment: You might be after... `requests.post(url, data=data, params={'username': 'user1', 'password': 'pass1'})`...

Comment: No with params={username': 'user1', 'password': 'pass1'}), I still get 'certificate verify failed'

Comment: Probably want read through http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification... You might want to rethink about sending it private data though if you disable that check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For bypassing certification check use (verify=False) :

```
response = requests.post('https://aaaa.bbb.com/:nnnn', data=data, verify=False)
```

and for ensuring to send data as url encoded :

```
response = requests.post('https://aaaa.bbb.com/:nnnn', data=data, verify=False, headers={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

Comment: I can circumvent certification check, but how do I include the username & password

Comment: It depend on your server definition, but so far you can send it via : response = requests.post('https://aaaa.bbb.com/:nnnn', 'username=user1&password=pass1', verify=False, headers={'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})

Comment: Agree. It works. Thanks. But I was wondering if I can include the certificate validation too.

Comment: Yes you can, by setting certification address to verify parameter. for example : verify='server.crt'

Answer (score 1):

The reason for `certificate_verify_failed` is perhaps because the client is trying to verify the server certificate and failing in doing so. You may disable the verification on the client side by using `verify=False`

```
import requests
url = "https://aaaa.bbb.com:nnnn"
headers = {}
data = {
    "id": "id1"
}
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)
```